# Adicionar contador regressivo javascript ao localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Fiz um contador regressivo usando javascript, que está funcionando direitinho. Porém queria que ao adicionar o evento ele gravasse no localstorage e permitisse fazer isso mais de uma vez, adicionando vários eventos e que todos ficassem com seu contador regressivo funcionando. Se alguém puder me dar um norte de como posso implementar isso, fico muito agradecida.

```js
let contador = document.getElementById('contador');

function agendar() {
  let nomeEvento = document.getElementById('nomeEvento').value;
  if (!nomeEvento) {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerText = 'Insira um nome para agendar seu evento'
  } else {
    let data = document.getElementById('date').value.split('-');
    let hour = document.getElementById('time').value.split(':');

    let dataEvent = new Date(...data, ...hour);
    dataEvent.setMonth(dataEvent.getMonth() - 1);


    let timer = setInterval(function() {

      let contagem = dataEvent.getTime();
      let atual = new Date().getTime();
      let distance = contagem - atual;

      let dias = Math.floor(distance / 86400000);
      let horas = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      let minutos = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      let segundos = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


      let formata = `{${nomeEvento}} começa em \n ${dias} dias \n ${horas < 10 ? '0' + horas : horas}h : ${minutos < 10 ? '0' + minutos : minutos}m : ${segundos < 10 ? '0' + segundos : segundos}s`;
      contador.innerText = formata;

      if (dias == 0 & horas == 0 & minutos == 0 & segundos == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        contador.innerText = `o ${nomeEvento} começou`;
      }
      if (dias < 0) {
        contador.innerText = 'Data ou hora inválida(s)';
        clearInterval(timer)
      }

    }, 1000)
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" class="form content">
    <input type="text" name="" id="nomeEvento" placeholder="Nome do Evento">
    <p>Data e hora do evento</p>
    <input type="date" name="" id="date">
    <input type="time" name="" id="time"> <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="agendar()">Iniciar</button>
  </form>
  <div id='contador' />
</div>
```

Comment: Sugiro você salvar o "Evento" no LocalStorage e resgatar quando abrir a página. Assim você calcula  o tempo que falta quando for exibi, do mesmo modo que faz quando clica em "Iniciar". Qual sua dúvida exatamente? Não sabe armazenar no LocalStorage ou estava pensando em mudar o "registro" a cada segundo?

Comment: @RafaelTavares, minha duvida é o que adicionar ao localStorage, e em que momento da execução, em um primeiro momento pensei em guardar o timer todo, mas não sei exatamente como fazer ou se é viável, ou se eu crio um objeto para armazenar os diferentes eventos. Estou um pouco perdida kkkkkk. Por isso queria uma idéia

Answer (score 1):

Para salvar no localStorage é preciso que a key seja uma [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), mas você não tem acesso á todas as chaves é preciso que seu programa lembre-se da chave, sua alternativa é mapear em uma `object` ou `array` e armazenar em uma `JSON string`, o qual você pode acessar, iterar e reiniciar a contagem de eventos.
A data pode ser salva em `ISOString` ou o `valueOf`, as 2 opções são viáveis pra re-criar o objeto. Seu código pode ser adaptado pra seguinte estrutura:

```js
let eventos = [ ['ev1Name', new Date().toISOString()], ['ev2Name', new Date().toISOString()] ];
// salva no storage em string
localStorage.setItem('agenda', JSON.stringify(eventos));

function checaAgenda() {
  let agenda = localStorage.getItem('agenda');
  eventos = agenda ? JSON.parse(agenda) : [];
  for (const evento of eventos) {
    iniciaContagem(evento);
  }
}

function iniciaContagem(evento) {
  // aqui o código da agenda
  console.log(evento[0], new Date(evento[1]));
}

// teste no console
eventos = [];
checaAgenda();
```